# Ping command argument

Tags: unix, web, ping

Why can I write the command

```
ping www.google.com
```

but not

```
ping www.google.com/
```

or

```
ping http://www.google.com
```

The latter two yield an "unknown host" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ping](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping) is used to tell if a host (hostname or IP address) is alive. It uses the ICMP protocol to do so. It does not know anything about URLs or web servers.

What you probably want is a `http ping` utility, like [http-ping](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/http-ping/). Or you can use tools like `curl`, or `wget` to retrieve website index pages and measure the latency that way.

Example with `curl` (this does a HEAD request):

```
$ time curl -I http://www.cnn.com >/dev/null

real    0m0.242s    <== 242 milliseconds
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.016s
```

Example with `curl` for GET request:

```
$ time curl http://www.cnn.com >/dev/null

real    0m0.783s    <== 783 milliseconds
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.030s
```

This will give you a *crude* idea of how responsive the web server is from your host.

Answer (score 1):

Because ping works with IP addresses or hostnames (resolves to IP for you).

`www.google.com` is a host, but `www.google.com/` and `http://www.google.com` are urls.